# Error trying to reference player from tag?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I trying to program an enemy ai and to do so I need to reference the player so the enemy can look at them  but the line I am trying to add is

```
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player").transform;
```

and it is giving me the error

```
"CS1061 'GameObject[]' does not contain a definition for 'transform' and no accessible extension 
method 'transform' accepting a first argument of type 'GameObject[]' 
could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [Assembly-CSharp]"
```

how can I fix this since the player is referenced as "Transform player;" so I am not sure why it does not work or how to fix this

Comment: Please use the correct tags. Your code is in `c#` not `c++` and your question is not related to a specific IDE at all ;)

Comment: You asked for all objects tagged Player. Therefore it can’t give you 48 (a random number but hey who knows) and know which transform you wanted. Perhaps you want to remove the S from objects

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer myself it was a simple mistake!
The line said

```
player = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player").transform;
```

and the mistake was that I used `FindGameObjectsWithTag` instead of `FindObjectWithTag`
Coding can be so tedious sometimes :D